# ORACLE - Create Procedure granted but can't create procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, privileges, ora-01031

There's a user in the database to whom CREATE PROCEDURE privelege is granted. But when that user tries to create a simple procedure the following error is thrown: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
           without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
           attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
           system privileges.

here's the DDL for the procedure:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TOTALBASE.ROUNDUP 
          (CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR  ) 
 AS 
 BEGIN
  OPEN CUR FOR
   SELECT * FROM TOTALBASE.ABONENT; 
 END ROUNDUP;
```

What else should I consider to do to make this work? I'm suspecting that even if the privelege is granted anyone who's not in the administrators or ORA_DBA group can't create a procedure. but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you in the `totalbase` schema when trying to create this procedure? It appears as though you're trying to add an object to `totalbase` from a different user...

Comment: No, I'm in a different schema. But I've granted that user CREATE PROCEDURE privelege. Isn't that enough for that?

Comment: Does that user also have SELECT permissions on the abonent table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To create a procedure in a schema other than your own, you'll need `CREATE ANY PROCEDURE` privilege.

As a general rule, this privilege should not be granted lightly, as it could easily be used to circumvent database security.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Believe me I'd granted that privelege too but I got the same problem. Then I revoked that privelege after seeing it did not help anyway.

Comment: Then I suggest that you re-grant the CREATE ANY PROCEDURE privilege, and try it again, with 'alter session set sql_trace = true;' to see what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

After few comments below, I am trying again.

Do not create a procedure in another schema; only let each user create objects in their own schema.

This way you have less of a reason to `GRANT` access to other schema objects. The `TOTALBASE` user can than grant the `EXECUTE` privilege on that procedure to current user.

The current user, which needs some data from a `TOTALUSER` table, does not need to create or access other objects when he has the `EXECUTE` privilege on function or procedure.

Looking from another angle, this way it's also easier to maintain: `TOTALUSER` provides sort of an API in how it exposes data to the current user, hiding implementation details which can change in the future, being transparent to current user.

Comment: -1. This is the opposite of what the OP is trying to do, as explained in the question and the comments beneath.

Comment: What he is trying to do is not OK in 99%+ of cases. What he asks != what he needs to do. This is **very** dangerous to grant. As general guideline avoid any grants for other schemas (grant containing ANY keyword). Even thing that can look benign like granting SELECT, thinking it's read-only, can have unexpected effects ( like select ... for update )

Comment: I understand that and if you edit your answer to include a solution to the question and a clear explanation of _why_ that solution is wrong and what should be done instead I will reverse the downvote and depending on how much I agree with your answer may upvote as well. Look at @Mark's answer he's answered the question and then said that it probably shouldn't be done and why. As it stands though your answer doesn't really help. The OP is aware that they can create the procedure in the same schema.